# Rust: how to override the default way of reporting error?

Tags: rust

When error occurs in Rust, most Rust standard and 3rd party libraries (e.g. anyhow) would simply print the error message to stdout/stderr. What I need is to override it with my own function. For example, call Windows API [MessageBox](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-messagebox) with the location information (which file and line does it panic).

So far, I tried several methods and each lacks something.

1. Write my custom error, and overrides its `Debug` trait. The problem is that this error type needs to be able to wrap any underlying error (e.g. `dyn std::error::Error`), so that I could still write

```
fn test() -> std::result::Result<(), CustomError> {
  ...
  if (has_windows_error) {
    return Err(WindowsError(123))?;
  }
  if (has_io_error) {
    return Err(IoError(123))?;
  }

  Ok(())
}
```

However, this means CustomError needs to implement both `std::error::Error` and `From<std::error::Error>`, which conflicts against each other.

2. Write my custom result type, and implement `Try`. This approach requires touching the experimental `#![feature(try_trait_v2)]`.
3. Use `std::panic::set_panic_hook()`, then never use `?` in the code. Instead, only immediately `unwrap()` all `Result`s. This is needed because if I allow the error to bubble up, I will lose the location information in `PanicInfo`.

I'm relatively new to Rust, so I could have been missing many things. Option 3 is what I'm currently using, though I don't like how it forces me to abandon idiomatic coding style.

What is the cleanest, less intrusive way to implement custom error outputting currently?

Comment: the trick here is not to panic I guess. Just retrieve the error and do whatever you need with the information (aka, send it to the message box). I don't think you assumption on PanicInfo is completly right.

Comment: The problem is `main()` could call multiple functions that return `Result`. I will have to move the whole main code to a separate function, make it return `Result`, and catch that `Result`, send to MessageBox. Again, it forces me to change how I normally code.

Comment: well, going out of your is still better than trying to transform an error into a panic, then into an error again IMO

Comment: Wrapping `main()` isn't very intrusive at all, is it? It's a change in only two places (the signature of the wrapped main function, and the new `main()` which is just a few simple lines). As a bonus, it lets you unit test your wrapped main function!

Comment: Is having a wrapping `main()` a idiomatic way in Rust? If so I guess I could go with that. But I'm kinda surprised Rust requires users to do this just to have alternate error handling.

Comment: I don't think it's an uncommon pattern to have `main` limited to setup and tear-down even in other languages, with tear-down in this case including reporting errors via a message box. I'd argue that, at least without try blocks, wrapping `main` is idiomatic. Also, this kind of code modification isn't "alternate" error handling, it's just regular error handling. The `try { block } catch(..)` of Rust (at least currently) is `match block_in_fn() { Ok(..) => .., Err(..) => .. }`. This is because errors are return values, not exceptions.

Comment: Where is the error get printed? Libraries don't usually print errors. They either bubble them up or panic. If you want to messagebox on panics, you should set the panic hook. If the errors are bubbling, you can just catch 'em yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Option 3 is most certainly not the way to go here. In Rust panics mean unrecoverable errors, and from my experience with the community over the last 2 years this guideline is taken pretty seriously. Moreover options 1 and 2 add pretty substantial side-effects to operations which were never meant to hide stuff like that.

Also I'm not sure what you mean by "3rd party libraries (e.g. anyhow) would simply print the error message to stdout/stderr." If your function returns an `anyhow::Result<T>` and an error occurs, then all that happens is that error is converted into `anyhow::Error`, it's not printed unless you print it.

The bottom line is that there's no "error handling framework" in Rust. `Results` are not special at all, in fact I encourage you to read [the source code](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/src/core/result.rs.html#503-513). If you want to handle a result in a certain way, then match on it and write the code to handle it. Moreover the panic handling machinery is not meant to  elevate them to something like C++ exceptions. You can read more about the motivations for it [here](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/master/text/1236-stabilize-catch-panic.md).

It sounds like what would work best for you is using `anyhow` or something like it, and at some point in your program you can match on a result, convert the `anyhow::Error` (or `std::error::Error` implementer of your choice) to a string and open a message box. If you want to include file and line information about where the error occurred, then that could be added to the error's message/data via the [`file!`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/macro.file.html) and [`line!`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/macro.line.html) macros provided through the standard library. This could look something like the following:

```rs
pub fn main() {
    if let Err(error) = try_main() {
        // show_message_box implementation not shown
        show_message_box(error.to_string());
    }
}

pub fn try_main() -> anyhow::Result<()> {
    // code which makes extensive use of `?`
}
```

Note that Rust's approach to error handling is different from many other widely used languages, so it's going to require a shift in coding style. Errors are deliberately meant to be intrusive in your code so you actually handle them properly, which is something I came to greatly appreciate with time. In fact, Rust's idiosyncrasies make it a very opinionated language, so when you reach pain points I would advice against trying to solve them by using language features beyond their intended use, as that's more likely to cause additional pain points than to solve your problem.

Comment: I basically want to have something like in Java: wrap the whole main in a try catch `Exception` and message box that Exception with its original location. I don't see how I can get the original location through a `std::error::Error`. Where do you put `file!` and `line!`?

Comment: You could write a simple macro to help make that convenient with `anyhow` ([example here](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=37be3929b4a17c16f218b355167af680)). Most of the time in Rust I've gone without file/line information and been just fine because errors are generally much more descriptive. There is a tracking issue for [`try` blocks](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/31436) but that hasn't landed yet, so adding `try_main` and matching on that in `main` is accomplishing the equivalent.